# How do you access a website and read it's contents in c?

Tags: c, json, api

I'm trying to access a website url(https) and read back it's contents(a json from an api).
What c commands would I use?

Comment: like `wget www.google.com`?

Comment: hmm, this doesn't do anything in my terminal.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you looked at [libcurl](http://curl.haxx.se/)?  Never used it, but I've seen it used quite a bit.  Otherwise it's going to be somewhat system dependant, if you're on linux you could use popen() on a command that dumps to stdout.

Comment: cURL is indeed the "go to" library for programatic HTTP operations.